# 2nd order differential equation: $y''+y=xe^x\cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How can I solve the following differential equation?

$$y''+y=xe^x\cos(x)$$

I've studied the (1) Undeterminate Coefficients, (2) Variation of Parameters and (3) Laplace Transforms methods, but I don't know which of them to use since $xe^x\cos(x)$ is too complicated for (1), I don't know how to solve the integral I obtain with (2) and I don't have the initial values for (3). What should I do?

Comment: For LTs, just call your initial conditions $y_0$ and $y'_0$ and work away.

Comment: Check this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288844/differential-equation-non-homogeneous-solution-finding-yp/289339#289339).

Answer (score 1):

For Laplace transforms, define $Y(s)$ as the LT of $y(x)$.

Use integration by parts to establish that the LT of $y''(x)$ is $s^2 Y(s) - y_0 s - y'_0$, where $y_0=y(0)$ and $y'_0 = y'(0)$.

You will also need to take the LT transform of the RHS:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \, x \, e^x \, \cos{x} \, e^{-s x} &= \int_0^{\infty} dx \, x \cos{x} \, e^{-(s-1) x}\\ &= - \frac{d}{d(s-1)} \Re{\left [\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-[(s-1)-i] x} \right ]}\\&= -\frac{d}{d(s-1)} \left [\frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}\right ] \\ &= \frac{(s-1)^2-1}{[(s-1)^2+1]^2} \end{align} $$

Then

$$Y(s) = \frac{(s-1)^2-1}{[(s-1)^2+1]^2 (s^2+1)} + \frac{y_0 s+y'_0}{s^2+1}$$

To find $y(x)$, apply an inverse LT either using tables or the residue theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The given eq. is

$$y''+y=xe^x\cos(x)$$
$$(D^2+1)y=xe^x\cos(x)$$

Now firstly we have to find C.F

A.E is $m^2+1=0$  & $m=+i,-i$

Hence $C.F=c_1sinx+c_2cosx$

Now we have to calculate P.I

=$\left(\frac{1}{D^2+1}\right) xe^x\cos(x)$

=$e^x\left(\frac{1}{(D+1)^2+1}\right)x\cos(x)$

=$e^x\left(\frac{1}{D^2+1+2D}\right)x\cos(x)$

=$e^x.x\left(\frac{1}{f(D)}\right)cos(x)$ -$ e^x\left(\frac{1}{f(D)^2}\right)
[f'(D)cos(x)$

=$e^x.x sinx -e^x sinx$

Hence complete solution is

$y=C.F+P.I=c_1sinx+c_2cosx+e^x.x sinx -e^x sinx$