# Find the general solution for the differential equation $(D^2+4D+4)y=5xe^{-2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for the differential equation $(D^2+4D+4)y=5xe^{-2x}$

Attempt: $y_c(x)=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2xe^{-2x}$ and  $y_p(x)=Ax^2e^{-2x}$. Moreover $y'_p(x)=2Axe^{-2x}-2Ax^2e^{-2x}$ and $y_p''(x)=2Ae^{-2x}-8Axe^{-2x}+4Ax^2e^{-2x}$
So $A=5x/2$. So the general solution is $y(x)=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2xe^{-2x}+(5/2)x^3e^{-2x}$. 
But the answer says that the genral solution is $y(x)=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2xe^{-2x}+(5/6)x^3e^{-2x}$. I am very new in differential equations. Did I mistake somewhere?Thanks!

Comment: I gave the technique in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288844/differential-equation-non-homogeneous-solution-finding-yp/289339#289339).

Comment: i have the same solution

Comment: The solution is correct. Good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be easily solved directly.  Multiplying both sides by $e^{2x}$ yields

$$e^{2x}y''+4e^{2x}y'+4e^{2x}y=(e^{2x}y)''=5x$$

Integrating twice and multiplying by $e^{-2x}$ gives the solution you've obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Since $D^2+4D+4=(D+2)^2$, you can write
$$(D+2)^2y=5xe^{-2x}\Rightarrow y=\frac1{(D+2)^2}5xe^{-2x}.$$
Therefore, the particular integral is
$$y=e^{-2x}\frac1{(D-2+2)^2}5x=e^{-2x}\frac1{D^2}5x=e^{-2x}\frac{5x^3}6.$$