# How to solve $y'''-y=x+1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve ODE:

$$y'''-y=x+1$$

To find the particular solution, I thought to impose

$$y_p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

Fair Enough? Or should I consider other?

Comment: Since the RHS is linear it is enough to consider $y_p(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: It is clear that $y=-(x+1)$  works.

Comment: You know it can't be higher than $x$ Because the third derivative removes all powers up to cube and you can't balance the order 2 terms on the lhs.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768755/how-to-solve-y-y-2-sinx/768785#768785).

Comment: You can use the [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288844/differential-equation-non-homogeneous-solution-finding-yp/289339#289339) I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic equation is $$r^3-1=(r-1)(r^2+r+1)=0$$ so we have that $$r=1,  \ \\ r=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3} i}{2}$$ From this, you can obtain the solution of the homogeneous equation $$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}\cos\frac{\sqrt{3} }{2}x+c_3e^{-\frac{1}{2}x}\sin\frac{\sqrt{3} }{2}x$$ and he particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation is $$y_p=Ax+B.$$ Now  if you replace the expression on the RHS of the above formula you can find $A$ and $B$. Therefore, the general solution of the equation is $$y=y_h+y_p$$