# Differential equation with the solution of $(1+ax/2)\exp(-ax)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Is there any linear differential equation which has following solution

> $$y=(1+ax/2)\exp(-ax)$$
>   $a$ is constant.

Comment: For all $a$ or a given $a$?

Comment: Is $a$ a variable or a constant? If $a$ is a constant, this question can be considered in the category of ordinary differential equation. Try to write down the general solution of a linear ordinary differential equation and compare it with the item in the question.

Comment: No, a is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = (1 + ax/2)e^{-ax}$ and $D = d/dx$. Note that,
$$
2ay = 2ae^{-ax} + a^2xe^{-ax} 
$$
$$
2Dy = 2D\biggl(e^{-ax} + \dfrac{axe^{-ax}}{2}\biggr) = -2ae^{-ax} + ae^{-ax} -a^2xe^{-ax} = ae^{-ax} - 2ay \quad \Rightarrow
$$
$$
2D^2y = D(2Dy) = -a^2e^{-ax} - 2aDy = -a(ae^{-ax}) - 2aDy \quad \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
2D^2y + 2aDy = -a(2Dy + 2ay) \quad \Rightarrow \quad (D^2 + 2aD + a^2)y = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (D + a)^2y = 0
$$
or
$$
y^{\prime \prime} + 2ay^{\prime} + a^2y = 0   
$$
General solution: $y = C_1e^{-ax} + C_2xe^{-ax}$

Answer (score 1):

For all differentiable functions $y=f(x)$, one can always obtains a linear ode by taking derivative on both sides. Say, $f(x)=(1+ax/2)\exp{(-ax)}$ has immediately ode
$$y'(x)=f'(x)=-a(1+ax)\exp{(-ax)}/2$$

Comment: I mean something like $y'' + a^2y' + ay = 0$

Comment: @Hesam So why not write it down and verify?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach. Let

> $$ y = (1+a\,x/2)e^{-ax} \longrightarrow (*) $$

Differentiating w.r.t. $x$ both sides we have

> $$ y'= -a(1+ax/2)e^{-ax}+\frac{a}{2}e^{-ax} $$

Using $(*)$ we get

$$  y'=-y+\frac{a}{2}\frac{y}{(1+ax/2)} $$

> $$ \implies y' = \left(\frac{a}{2}\frac{1}{(1+ax/2)}-1\right)y,\quad y(0)=1. $$

**Added:** I already introduced a technique for the question you are asking in my previous work. See for instance [section 6, lemma 1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KZWIzZjIxZGQtN2M4NC00N2MzLTk1YmQtM2M2NmVhYmE4NzA5/edit?hl=en_US) or see my [book](https://www.morebooks.de/search/gb?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mhenni). Another approach is the [annihilator techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256429/use-two-solutions-to-a-high-order-linear-homogeneous-differential-equation-with/256462#256462).

Comment: Thanks, but this is not linear.

Comment: @Hesam: Of course it is linear! Just review the definition of linear differential equations.

Comment: I see but I need something like $y'' + a^2y' + ay = 0$

Comment: @Hesam: That's a different question. See what I added.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you want a **constant-coefficient** homogeneous linear differential equation, you'll want the characteristic polynomial to have a double root at $-a$.

Comment: How did you guess?